# iPad scroling on a Jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a (`#Accordion`) inside a div(`.summary_wrapper`) inside of a iFrame(`desktopIframe`) inside of a div(`.desktop_summary_column_div`).Hope it makes sense. The height of the accordion collapsed is NOT taller than the div(`.summary_wrapper`). If I expand a accordion item, it expands past the bottom of the div(`.summary_wrapper`) (which is also the bottom of the ipad screen). If I want to scroll down the ipad wants to move/scroll the whole screen. This means the containing div moves with the drag of my finger. So this renders scrolling on my accordion as useless.

It there a way to setup the accordion to allow scrolling inside the div for ipads?

Here is my setup for the accordion.

```
      $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ 
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true, 
        active: false,
        // autoheight: true,
        animated: 'easeslide'
    });


    var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
    if(is_touch_device) {
        $(this).addClass('panel');
        $(this).addClass('overflow');
    }
  });
```

here is a example of the containing elements.

```
<td class="desktop_summary_column">
<div class="desktop_summary_column_div" style="display: block;">
    <iframe id="desktopIframe" name="desktopIframe" width="100%" height="99%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    ..........
        <body>
            <div class="overview_wrapper"> 
                <div class="summary_wrapper">
                    <div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" role="tablist">
                        <div class='desktop_summary_text'>                          
                            ...ACCORDION ITEM with sub items...
                        </div>
                        <div class='desktop_summary_text'>                          
                            ...ACCORDION ITEM with sub items...
                        </div>
                        <div class='desktop_summary_text'>                          
                            ...ACCORDION ITEM with sub items...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    ..........
</div>
```

on the `.desktop_summary_text` class on the very inside of the accordion I have the following styles set up.

```
.panel
{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 300px; /* fixed height of div */  
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* allow touch scrolling in webkit browsers */
 }           

.panel > * {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
}


.overflow {
    /*overflow: scroll;*/  /*set overflow to scroll for desktop browsers*/ 
    /*overflow-x: hidden; */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.accordion{
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Im sorry, I know its quite a load of...
But maybe it might make sense to a few people that will be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer

adding the following style to the DIV containing the iFrame.

**style="overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch"**

```
<div class='desktop_summary_column_div' style="overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch">
```